# dev.azure.com, can add user, but can;t change a password

Tags: azure-devops

I set up a small Azure DevOps site, so me and a friend can work together.

So to test things, I invited myself via another mailadress, which seems to work: I get an invite and can access the site throuh that invite, but if I click the link I'm logged in under the main credential....

Is is possible to set individual passwords? Because when I check the users tab in the Organization settings, I can only change access levels and package management etc... Nor is a password supplied in the invotation mail and cant change my own either...

curious stuff.

Is it at all possible to changes these passwords?

-> just reminded myself... perhaps the users need an msdn account hehe. Check tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with passwords (or changing them), it has to do with your browser's cached credentials.

You need to log out or use an incognito/private browser with your alternate account.

Comment: No, i cant physically give a newly invited user a password, of change one of an existing user in the the user tab. Just revoke rights etc.

Comment: No, you can't manage passwords. They manage their passwords by creating a Microsoft account. That's what I'm saying: You need to log out and log in with a different Microsoft account.

Comment: Yeah, the quarter didnt fell at first. Thanks. Makes perfect sense.